# How to hide div in html from controller js file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to hide and show the div element in html from controller js file using angularjs

```
$scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
    { 
        field: 'name', enableSorting: true, width: "10%", textAlign: "middle", cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click=\"showme=true\">{{row.entity.name}}</a></div>'
    }
]};
```

for example i have given the clicked name for view. From this i want to show another div in html page.

In simple, from angularjs file when clicking the row value from the datagrid thee table should hide and another div should enable to show.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: You can use 'ng-hide' & 'ng-show' attibutes on your div

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing so the angular way:

1. using [`ng-show`/ `ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) (element is still in the DOM but has `display: none;`)
2. using [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) (element will be removed from / added to DOM)